# Sitecore Item Web API does not return any field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore8

I am using the Sitecore Item Web API for a Sitecore 7.5 and 8. And in both I am getting a empty list for the fields in the JSON returned.

Sample of request:

```
GET http://sitecore8/-/item/v1/?sc_database=web&sc_itemversion=1&language=default&payload=Content&scope=s&sc_itemid=%7b11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111%7d HTTP/1.1
X-Scitemwebapi-Username: sitecore\admin
X-Scitemwebapi-Password: b
Host: sitecore8
Connection: Close
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 18 May 2015 17:54:53 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 597

{"statusCode":200,"result":{"totalCount":1,"resultCount":1,"items":[{"Database":"web","DisplayName":"sitecore","HasChildren":true,"Icon":"/temp/IconCache/Applications/32x32/Document.png","ID":"{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}","Language":"en","LongID":"/{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}","MediaUrl":"/temp/IconCache/Applications/48x48/Document.png","Name":"sitecore","Path":"/sitecore","Template":"System/Root","TemplateId":"{C6576836-910C-4A3D-BA03-C277DBD3B827}","TemplateName":"Root","Url":"~/link.aspx?_id=11111111111111111111111111111111\u0026amp;_z=z","Version":1,"Fields":{}}]}}
```

Does anybody has any idea what I am missing?

Tks a lot..

Comment: Try to change `payload=content` to `payload=full`

Comment: As Marek states, changing that setting will likely be the answer. In the example above you are requesting the fields for the Sitecore node with the content payload . With this setting the api will only bring back the content fields for the item excluding system fields. The sitecore node doesn't have any content fields hence an empty fields collection

Comment: So actually you might be better off keeping the content setting and requesting a different item rather than the sitecore node.

Comment: Hi, thanks guys. I've tried already with Full payload. Actually I've played around with all the properties, payload, scope, extractblob, etc. Also it is happening in the custom implementation I want to use it and in a fresh sitecore 8 installation I have here.

Comment: In the sample I got above I am using the 1111(...) item. But I have also tried with a few other real content items.

Comment: Tks Marek & gg. someone commented out the processor to get the fields. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Damm..  the processor to get the fields were commented out in my configuration files.

```
<itemWebApiGetFields>
        <!--<processor type="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.GetFields.GetFields, Sitecore.ItemWebApi" />-->
</itemWebApiGetFields>
```